# Tailwind custom breakpoints are overriding larger breakpoints

Tags: tailwind-css, sveltekit

I'm using the latest version of tailwind and I have a custom breakpoint, `xs:`, which is equal to 540px. When I use it like this: `h-[420px] xs:h-[400px] xl:h-[360px]` it works fine for mobile and the xs breakpoint, but the xl breakpoint no longer registers- the height is 400 even on desktop.

This is my config:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
      'xs': '540px',
      ...
```

Unfortunately, this works in the sandbox [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Vqkh6ZTGdl) and I'm not sure why it doesn't work on my local. I'm using Sveltekit (a version before the breaking changes), Ubuntu Linux and Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

not sure which version of tailwind you're using, probably a version number would help, but in the latest version of tailwind, you cant simply extend smaller breakpoints because the new breakpoint will be added at the end of the breakpoints list.

> If you want to add an additional small breakpoint, you can’t use extend because the small breakpoint would be added to the end of the breakpoint list, and breakpoints need to be sorted from smallest to largest in order to work as expected with a min-width breakpoint system.

> Instead, override the entire screens key, re-specifying the default
> breakpoints:

```html
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'xs': '475px',
      ...defaultTheme.screens,
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

you can read more here : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens#adding-smaller-breakpoints

Comment: My tailwind version is 3.2.2. This didn't fix my problem

Answer (score -2):

Standard CSS3 give us to max and min values for responsive behaviors.

But tailwind responsive behaviors set as default for only min size.
what it mean ?

if you add one more responsive behavior point...
you must stop that 'xs' behaviors with sm:h-[360px] or md:h-[360px].
if you don't understand this answer, i can give you more details about it.

But please add your code more with details.

Comment: I do use the sm and md breakpoints, but they don't work on elements that also use the xs breakpoint.

Comment: You don't understand 'what i say brother.'
Please look little basic css for 'min/max media queries how to works ?' .

Please try understand basic css media queries carefully.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens